# sorting of infinite positive vector from $\ell_{1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, sorting

Let us consider the sequence space $\ell_{1}$. Next, let $\mathcal{X} \subset \ell_{1}$ be a subset of $\ell_{1}$ of all vectors with non-negative elements.

Can we then define operator $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$, such that for $x\in \mathcal{X}$ we have $f(x) = sort(x)$, where $sort$ is sorting in non-increasing order. I mean, is the operator $f$ well-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function $f$ is well-defined, because for each element $x\in\mathcal X\subset \ell^1$
we have
$$\|x\|_{\ell^1} = \|\operatorname{sort}(x)\|_{\ell^1},$$
and therefore you have $f(x)\in\mathcal X\subset\ell^1$.

slightly Off-topic: Note that $f$ is not linear, but it can be shown to be Lipschitz-continuous, but this is not so simple to show.

Comment: could you, please, edit you reply? it seems that latex is not perfect there.

Comment: Hey, I'm curious about your OT claim! Do you have a reference about the Lipschitz continuity of sorting? Or at least, could you say a bit more about it?

Comment: @AspectStalence it has been a while, so I do not have a reference ready and do not recall the approach. I would need to think about it. If I do not reply today, feel free to ask a question about it. I think it has a decent chance of getting an answer.